# How to create pipe without buffer in C?

Tags: c, buffer, posix, pipe

I want to create pipe without buffer, but I've found only `setbuf()` function that works only for file descriptors. Can you suggest something similar to it for pipes?

Comment: On Linux, you can change it using the [`F_SETPIPE_SZ` fcntl](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fcntl), but it's always rounded up to at least a page size and the system can increase it as it sees fit. In other words, zero is not possible using that method.

Comment: Do you mean unbuffered or maybe non-blocking?  On Linux, see `man 7 pipe` and `O_NONBLOCK`.  There is an explanation of `PIPE_BUF` there as well.

Comment: Of course it's not possible to create a pipe without a buffer, because a pipe is really nothing more than a buffer in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

If you created the pipe with [`pipe`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/pipe), then you have already unbuffered file descriptors, besides the system buffers of course.

[`setbuf`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/setbuf) is for stdio files only and doesn't interfere, if you use plain system file descriptors.

Comment: Although if you want to *add* buffering to a pipe, you can use [`fdopen(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fdopen) along with `setbuf`.